# Learn spelling keyboard shortcut

Tags: spellcheck

Apple spellchecker is very useful, but does not work very well for technical text as it is missing all brand names and 50% words, doing more damage than good.

[image]

Is there a way to do "Learn spelling" action as a keyboard shortcut, so that I don't need to go through *painful* learn spelling right menu click every time. This starts to hurt after it is miscorrecting 100th word.

EDIT: Tried to add shortcut, but doesn't seem to work:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how often you are writing new words, but on occasion I need to right click. It seems like you are doing it for every other word. Have you gone into Sys Prefs>Keyboard>Shortcuts>All Applications, and added a shortcut?

Comment: Please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

No.
Workaround, press  ⌘ + :
That is Command + Shift + Semicolon

The Spelling and grammar dialogue box will appear; all you have to do is keep clicking learn with the mouse, it will automatically move to the next one  [image: Here]

Comment: Nice try but this does not answer the question because the directions you provide still involves the mouse. And as the document is expanded, it needs to be done again and again.